# div background-color match to the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have divs here

1.this div is for background img

```
<div id="background"><img src="img/layout/bg_home.png" height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
```

2. container-fluid div inclues three major divs inside(nav-row,content-row,footer-row)
   in content-row div includes two parts(home-log, home-copy)

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="content-area"> <div class="row-fluid" id="nav-row"> </div><!-- ./row-fluid --><div class="row-fluid" id="content-row"><div class="row-fluid" id="content-row">
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4" id="home-logo">
            <img src="img/layout/logo.png" id="logo">

                  <ul id="subnav">
                        <!-- Loaded via AJAX -->
                  </ul>

          </div><!-- ./span4 -->
          <div class="span8" id="home-copy">
            <p id="home-p">
                Foxcode is an investment and merchant banking Firm which advises and invests in small to mid-market companies and projects globally.
            </p>
          </div><!-- ./span8 -->
        </div><!-- ./row-fluid -->
      </div><!-- span12 -->
    </div><!-- ./row-fluid -->div class="row-fluid" id="footer-row">
      <div class="span12">
      <ul id="footer-list">
        <li>&copy; 2013 Foxcode, Inc. All Rights Reserved</li>
        <li> | </li>
        <li>Legal</li>
        <li>Sitemap</li>
        <li>Privacy</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      </div><!-- ./span12 -->
    </div><!-- ./row-fluid -->
```

my question is : i want my home-log/home-copy bck-color go down to the bottom in each page.
             how do I do that ?  thank you

Comment: honestly , this stuff was built from my previous coworker, he quits the job. So I just get request from client and need to make some change.

Comment: i followed what you said, but the issue still there . any suggestion?

Comment: FYI, Han, his suggestion wasn't a solution. Though, looking at the page it looks like you found one. I was going to say, with the way it's laid out, you'll probably need a JS method to calculate height of those 2 boxes. Also I gave you your point back. People on SO have become mean and useless lately. So much `negging` without any real purpose other than to make themselves feel better about the fact they can't answer the question.

Comment: Hi SpYk3HH, I understand what you said.  there are more issue coming up. for example, what range you can see depends on you previous webpage    do you know how does it happen?

Comment: I'm looking at it on and off between work and work. So far I don't see any big issue except some ol' skool style script writing, but I'm sure I'll find it eventually.

Comment: in main.js, in handleAjax(eBtn), I set an alert($(document).height());i found out the height of document will accumulate by itself, which means that if you click about/about,about/difference, and about/stretegy then go back to about/about,  the height of about/about will be higher than before

Comment: That helps alot, thank you. I see that, I'm looking it over along with a few other things. I'll get you an answer asap.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31268/discussion-between-han-and-spyk3hh)